# Decibel calculation using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio, media-player

//decibel calculation using media player

/*Decibel calculation using media player??

Hello All, I have a requirement that i want to play an audio file using media player.

and i want to calculate decibel values of the on going playing sound simultaneously now i had stuck in calculating decibel values using media player.

Any suggestions are appreciated but i do not want to use audio track due to some other requirements So any one can help me in calculating decibels using MP.
*/